# How to change a value of a field in an ArrayList of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know how to add an object:

```
ArrayList<Object> ob = new ArrayList<Object>();

ob.add (index, some_object);
```

But let say the object has a field called 'name', how can I change that single field only?
For example:

```
ob.setName(name);
```

(I know this does not work.)

Comment: Not sure if an Arraylist is the best option for your case. Why do you want to update a property of an item in an arrayList? Can you describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: Unrelated. Give meaningful names to the variables. It's misleading to name a list `ob`. Common practice would be something like `objects` (i.e. **plural form**) or something like that...

Comment: ob.get(index).setName("nameToBeSet");

Answer (score 2):

There's no special treatment here:

```
ArrayList<SomeObjectType> ob = new ArrayList<SomeObjectType>();
//...
ob.add(index, some_object);
some_object.setName(name);
```

The object you wanted to set name for is `some_object`, not `ob`.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure he shouldn't use ArrayList<Object> if you want to use fields from it. At least cast it before.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about a situation where you have a `List` which contains the object you want to update, but you don't yet have a reference to that object, then you will need to first *find* the object within the list, and then update its `name` field.

If you do have the reference to the object, then the fact that it is contained in a list is irrelevant: call `some_object.setName(name)` and the object will have the new name whether it is fetched from the list or directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think *maybe* you want to see

```
public void stuff(List<? extends Foo> list, int indexToAlter){
     // Get the item in the list at the index and call the appropriate method
     list.get(indexToAlter).methodOnFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing the list you are storing your object in and the object itself. Try something like:

```
    Object temp = ob.get(index);
    temp.name = new_name;
```